# Setting state on componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

I know that it is an anti-pattern to set state on `componentDidMount` and a state should be set on `componentWillMount` but suppose I want to set the length of the number of `li` tags as a state. In that case, I can't set the state on `componentWillMount` since the `li` tags might not have been mounted during that phase. So, what should be the best option here? Will it be fine if I set the state on `componentDidMount`?

Comment: do you render the `li` tags based on some props (or data)?  Could you just use `data.length`?

Comment: just putting it simply. say i've 4 `li` tags and i want to get the count of them so that my `maxNumber` state should be 4. however, i do render the `li` tags based on some props (or data).

Comment: Then use the data from props in `getInitialState()` to calculate the max, and put it in state there. There does not seem to be a need to wait for component to be mounted.

Comment: what about async data?

Comment: Dont set derived values to state.  In your render function use `const numLi = liList.length`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It is not an anti-pattern to call `setState` in `componentDidMount`. In fact, ReactJS provides an example of this in [their documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html):

> You should populate data with AJAX calls in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. This is so you can use setState to update your component when the data is retrieved.

**[Example From Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)**

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: `setState` is done in a callback function here - that's a bit of a [different scenario](http://jaketrent.com/post/set-state-in-callbacks-in-react/)

Comment: i'm not sure it's an anti-pattern. the [current documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) mentions that setting state in `componentDidMount` will trigger re-rendering, but there's no mention of it being bad practice.

Comment: @worc this answer describes that it's not an anti-pattern.

Comment: so, just to clarify for anyone else stumbling across this question and answer, the lifecycle function `isMounted` is deprecated and using it to set component state is considered an anti-pattern. setting state through `componentDidMount` is not considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment that there is a [Github discussion on this](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/684) and it is recommended if you are doing some server-side rendering or request for data to call setState in componentDidMount. However, the reason this is usually not recommended is because it can trigger a double render (see the [eslint rule no-did-mount-set-state](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md#prevent-usage-of-setstate-in-componentdidmount-reactno-did-mount-set-state)

Comment: @lux I don't recall the specifics here, but I think I was just pointing out that the mechanics were a little different here - the original question did not appear to require an async call to set the desired state. I didn't mean to indicate your code was invalid :)

Comment: As @Luis Perez stated in his answer. It will call the `render()` twice. I think it will cause a performance issues. I used `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`  which does the job and called the `render()`  once.

Answer (score 36):

According to the React Documentation it's perfectly OK to call `setState()` from within the `componentDidMount()` function.

It will cause `render()` to be called twice, which is less efficient than only calling it once, but other than that it's perfectly fine.

You can find the documentation here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Here is the excerpt from the documentation:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will
> trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser
> updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will
> be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate
> state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes
> performance issues...

Answer (score 5):

The only reason that the linter complains about using `setState({..})` in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` is that when the component render the setState immediately causes the component to re-render.
But the most important thing to note: using it inside these component's lifecycles is not an anti-pattern in React.

Please take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/684). you will understand more about this topic.
Thanks for reading my answer.