# Can't call setState on an unmounted component (Async still running)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an asynchronous function like so:

```
componentDidMount() {

    someAsyncFunction().then((data) => { 
      this.setState({ something: data });
    });

}
```

If go back to the previous screen, I will get the following error:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.

Is there something I can do to cancel this `setState()` if I go back to a previous screen while the async Is still running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850118/setting-state-on-componentdidmount

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting state on componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850118/setting-state-on-componentdidmount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this workaround:

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this._ismounted = true;
  someAsyncFunction().then((data) => {
    if (this._ismounted) {
      this.setState({ something: data });
    }
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this._ismounted = false;
}
```

This way the sesState will be called only if the component is mounted.
But this (as suggested in the comments) is an antiPattern and is to be used only when there is no another way to cancel the asyncFunction instead of waiting for it to be solved and then make the check.

Comment: React's documentation refers to a similar pattern, named cancelable promise - https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html, may add it to your answer if you wish

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not use isMounted() to wrap your code in an if-Statement.
(https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

In your case I think you have several choices: You could fire an action in your asynchronous function which sets the redux state instead of the components state.

Or if you really need it, you could set a flag in your componentDidMount and set it on false in componentWillUnmount.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        mounted: true
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({mounted: true});
    someAsyncFunction().then((data) => { 
        if(this.state.mounted) this.setState({ something: data });
    });
}


componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({mounted: false});
}
```