# How to check if map function is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, state, loading

### UPDATE: The process of what must happen

1. User drag and drops multiple pdf files
2. Each of these pdf files are then visually rendered one by one for the user in a list
3. As long as the list is still updating, a pop up will come up saying "please wait until everything is loaded"
4. After all the pdfs are loaded, the user can read the pdf in an embed to quickly check if this is what he wants to upload and can add a title and description for each pdf.
5. Every pdf has received an item; the user now clicks 'upload'

### Brief description

So I have a map function that loads a lot of items with large file size. I want to load each result one by one, but I want to hide or block it using a 'isLoading' state until everything is finished loading.

### Question

How do I check if a map function is finished loading everything?

### UPDATE: My code

```
{this.state.pdfSrc!== null ? // IF USER HAS UPLOADED FILES
    this.state.pdfSrc.map(item => ( // MAP THROUGH THOSE FILES
        // AS LONG AS THE MAP FUNCTION KEEPS LOADING FILES, A POP UP MUST COME UP SAYING "please wait until everything is loaded"
        <div key={item.fileResult} className='uploadResultList'>
                {item.fileName}
                <embed src={item.fileResult} />
                <input type='text' placeholder='Add title*' required />
        </div>
    )) /
: 
    null
}
```

**But this only gives me following error**

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if
>   you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe
>   you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: You might want to look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [Async/Await functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: What do you mean? Map is synchronous, so the next line of code won't execute until the map is complete.

Comment: Why do you have to render so many items at the same time? Is the user really able to gather all the data you are showing to him? Or would it better to add some pagination or "load on scroll" ? This has to be solved by a better UI, not better code.

Comment: To explain why I have to render so many items: Users will be able to upload multiple .pdf files. The reason why I'm showing all these items before uploading is because they will be able to add (for each item) a title, from & to date and other information. I had removed these to avoid a too long code structure as I was mainly focusing on how to know if a map is ending.

Comment: I have updated my answer and my code; hoping this may help understand what is happening and what I try to achieve
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this in a single function, you can implement the map in your component's render() method:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
     {!!imgSrc ? (
        <PlaceholderComponents/>
      ) : this.state.imgSrc.map(item => (
           <div key={item.fileResult} className='uploadResultList'>
            <embed src={item.fileResult} />
           </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, you would need to 'load' the file data before the doing so, either using componentDidMount or componentWillMount (which is now being deprecated, so try to avoid using it). For example:

```
    componentDidMount() {
      getImageSrcData(); // Either a function
      this.setState({ imgSrc: imgFile }) // Or from setState
    }
```

If you want more info on setting state from componentDidMount, see this thread:
[Setting state on componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850118/setting-state-on-componentdidmount)

**EDIT: You can use the React Suspense API to ensure the file loads before rendering...**

```
    // You PDF Component from a separate file where the mapping is done:

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
         {this.state.imgSrc.map(item => (
           <div key={item.fileResult} className='uploadResultList'>
             <embed src={item.fileResult} />
           </div>}
        </div>
       )
     }

    const PleaseWaitComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./PleaseWaitComponent'));


    render() {
      return (
      // Displays <PleaseWaitComponent> until PDFComponent loads
       <React.Suspense fallback={<PleaseWaitComponent />}>
         <div>
           <PDFComponent />
         </div>
       </React.Suspense>
     );
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if this answer is what I'm looking for. I'm actually searching for a solution to show a pop up with "please wait until everything is loaded" that shows up and leaves as soon as the files are done uploading (see updated answer

Comment: I see what you mean, can I get a bit more info? So...

- Do you load all the PDF info when the page loads? 
- Do you want to map function to run everytime the user drags a drops?

Comment: The page shows a list of pdfs previously uploaded by the user. (img, title and description). On 'upload' click, a pop up comes up where the user drag and drop new pdf files. The uploaded files are then put inside the pdfSrc state. In my render(), as soon as the state contains content; it starts a map() and loops through these files, showing a list to the user of what he's uploading. After adding a title and description to every pdf, he uploads it, api call updates the list and the page refreshes. Loading pdf files takes a while so I want to show a "wait" pop up until the map function is done.

Comment: @CédricBloem try React.Suspense and React.Lazy, it may help your loading issue without having to use setState in a single component. I;ve added an edit to my answer

Comment: I will try it and see what it gives. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @CédricBloem no worries, interesting problem

Comment: I got a chance to look back at the problem and came up with an idea that I had tried after trying your way. The problem was: after each uploaded pdf, I pushed data inside my state. Each time my state updated, my map updated; and so the loop goes on. Instead, I've rearranged my code to push everything after the for loop at once inside my state. The state updates only once and the map loops only one time through the state. Using this way, I was easily able to add a load bar like "file 1 of 3 uploaded" inside my forloop. I'm going to mark your answer as this one was also a solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update: You may need to look at creating a higher order component that can take another component and wait till all of those are loaded and then change the state. Perhaps something similar to [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)?

You don't need to pass a callback into the setState. .map isn't asynchronous and once the iteration has finished it will then move to the next line in the block.

The issue you're having here is that you're just calling map and returning JSX in the callback but it isn't going anywhere.

You should call the .map inside the render method. I'm not sure why you're trying to update the isLoading state. I think this should be handled elsewhere.

```
render() {
  cosnt { imgSrc } = this.state;
  return (
    {
      imgSrc.map(item => (
        <div key={item.fileResult} className="uploadResultList">
          <embed src={item.fileResult} />
        </div>
      ));
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this answer is what I'm looking for. I'm actually searching for a solution to show a pop up with "please wait until everything is loaded" that shows up and leaves as soon as the files are done uploading (I have updated my answer and my attempt code)

Comment: Updated my answer.