# Warning about unmounted component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that read values from an external devices, then these values are written in a DB. 
When I wrote this data in the db I receive this error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
>   cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

And It is about this code:

```
this.setState(state => ({
          acc_dx,
          array_acc_dx: [...state.array_acc_dx, [timeagm, ...acc_dx].join(":")]
        }));
```

this code is a part of a function **setupNotifications1** which in turn is called in a function called in the componentDidMount ().

How can I solve this warning? Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.deviceService1(this.device1);
  }
```

Inside `deviceService1()` I call `this.deviceService2(this.device2)` and inside I call `setupNotifications1(this.device1)` and `setupNotifications2(this.device2)`

**EDIT 2:**

```
async setupNotifications1(device) {
    var timeagm = 0;
    var time = 0;
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();


    this.subscriptionMonitor1 = await device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.AccGyrMg,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }

        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...acc_dx] = [2, 4, 6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({
          acc_dx,
          array_acc_dx: [...state.array_acc_dx, [timeagm, ...acc_dx].join(":")]
        }));
        timeagm += 20;
```

then I have a stop button that is used to remove this.subscriptionMonitor1 and change page ( I pass the value in the other page where there are written in the DB )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting state on componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850118/setting-state-on-componentdidmount)

Comment: show the entire `componentDidMount` function

Comment: @Oen44 No it's not :(

Comment: @Brandon I have edited the question

Comment: @Jack23 that still isn't really enough details. How long do these functions take, are they making API calls? If you unmount the component before the `setState` is able to happen, the functions will continue and this is where you'll see the error.

Comment: show the entire call stack from the start of componentDidMount to when this.setState() is called.

Comment: I Edit (2) my question :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if the react component is unmounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767482/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-react-component-is-unmounted)